# AS3 concat // MovieClip(parent).variable.gotoAndStop(otherVariable);

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there any concatenation problem in

```
MovieClip(parent).robes_position_num_clicked.gotoAndStop(traje1);
```

When I click on item n°2, `trace('robes_position_num_clicked')` returns "robes_position2", which is correct & what expected.

```
var index_clicked:int = myPositions.indexOf(e.target); // = Position num in array
var robes_position_num_clicked ="robes_position"+(index_clicked+1).toString();
  trace (robes_position_num_clicked);

 var traje1 = MovieClip(parent).robes_position1.currentLabel;

 if (   MovieClip(parent).robes_position1.currentLabel==traje1 &&  MovieClip(parent).robes_position1.currentLabel!=null)
    {   /*1*/ MovieClip(parent).robes_position2.gotoAndStop(traje1);
        /*2*/ MovieClip(parent).robes_position_num_clicked.gotoAndStop(traje1);   
      MovieClip(parent).robes_position1.gotoAndStop(1); 
    }
```

The first "sentence" /* 1*/ does the expected job,
while sentence /* 2*/ which is supposed to be a synonym, doesn't, and returns an error "One term is undefined and has no property".

Thanks for your lights as we say in french !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that `robes_position_num_clicked` here is just a `String` containing the name of your target `MovieClip` and not the `MovieClip` itself, so this line :

```
MovieClip(parent).robes_position_num_clicked.gotoAndStop(traje1);
```

should give you an error.

So, to access your `MovieClip` using its name, you can simply use the [`DisplayObjectContainer.getChildByName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.getChildByName()) function like this :

```
MovieClip(parent.getChildByName(robes_position_num_clicked)).gotoAndStop(traje1);
```

you can also do like this :

```
MovieClip(parent)[robes_position_num_clicked].gotoAndStop(traje1);
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: THANK U !!!! As I'm a beginner, I ignored that. But yes, that does the job, exactly what I was looking for. Thank u. :)

Answer (score 0):

robes_position_num_clicked  is a string not a MovieClip

"gotoAndStop" should be used with MovieClips not Strings ;

secondly: "robes_position_num_clicked" is defined in the current MovieClip not in the parent MovieCLip so it will be null in the parent MovieClip

Comment: I'm really not sure of what I'm supposed to do with what u just told me...<br />Do I have to type robes_position_num_clicked:MovieClip ??
<br /> Don't know what to do to solve that concern. Thanks

MovieClip(parent).robes_position_num_clicked.gotoAndStop(traje1);

Comment: Just make a movieClip in the parent MovieClip and name it "robes_position_num_clicked" or duplicate "robes_position2" and rename the new one "robes_position_num_clicked"

Comment: On stage, I have several mcs named robes_position1, robes_position2, robes_position3, etc etc etc... each containing their own 50 mcs. I was trying to target them thanks to my function (indexOf(e.target)), so I don't understand how & why should I duplicate them. Any link example ? Thks

Comment: Just use your target mcs name .change your /*2*/  line  into " MovieClip(parent).robes_position1.gotoAndStop(traje1);"

Comment: lol, yes /*1*/ does the job but is much too long! the point of all of that was: instead of using robes_position1, robes_position2, robes_position50, / I wanted to loop thru them thanks to indexOf . >>> 5 lines of code instead of 1500.. cause I dont only have dresses to handle but also shirts, pants, skirts, accessories, etc, so 50'000 lines of code !! I need to loop thru myPositions in 5 lines ;) 
`MovieClip(parent).robes_position_num_clicked.gotoAndStop(traje1);` is the solution but I need to find what's wrong with it. I'm sure it's the right solution, after some correction ... Thks